# Closing a teams messaging extension modal from an external service

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm opening (using OpenUrl) an external webpage I control. During loading of this web page, from the server I wish to close the teams modal either directly, or by invoking the teams client to resend message with a parameter, so the bot can respond with a close response (which I have working).

I'm able to do other tasks from an external service, like posting messages to existing or new chats. But when I try to set the activity type to invoke, I get BadRequest response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task Module modal dialog can be closed using `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask()` which is part of [Microsoft Teams JavaScript client SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest#using-the-sdk). This will closed the Task Module and submit the data back to Bot.

Please take a look at [Task Module sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp/blob/master/Microsoft.Teams.Samples.TaskModule.Web/Views/Home/CustomForm.cshtml#L22) to see how it's called from client code.